# Группировка значений и вывод в отдельный столбец

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, dataframe, python-3.5

Есть `DataFrame` в котором указан возраст пассажира. Нужно сгруппировать данные следующим образом:

```
df[df['Age'] <= 40] -  1 (young)
df[df['Age'] > 40] - 2 (old)
```

и вывести в отельную колонку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

можно сделать так:

```
df["new_col_name"] = (df['Age'] > 40) + 1
```

**пояснение:**

`df['Age'] > 40` - вернет булевый столбец. Если прибавить к булевым значениям единицу, то получим `1` вместо `False` и `2` вместо `True`.

**пример:**

```
In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame({"age": [20, 50, 60, 40]})

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
   age
0   20
1   50
2   60
3   40

In [27]: df["age"] > 40
Out[27]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: age, dtype: bool

In [28]: (df["age"] > 40) + 1
Out[28]:
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    1
Name: age, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно:)